# Firebase POST using curl via terminal timeout

Tags: curl, firebase

Firebase POST using curl via terminal resulting a timeout.
But it's running in Postman. Any suggestion?

Comment: "terminal", remote terminal or same ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this. For those who are having the same problem,

Any requests to Firebase without https will return a timeout.
 It was working with Postman, because Postman automatically change "http" request into "https".

[image: HTTPS is required]