# how i can import json file to firebase with php?

Tags: php, json, firebase

I have a json in my server, I want upload it on firebase. How I can do that with php? I found more guide online, but none of them helps me.

For example I have this code:

```
<?php
$firestore_key  = "xxx";
#Provide your firestore project ID Here
$project_id     = "smilelineallineatori-xmwrtf";

$object_unique_id = random_int(1,300);

$url = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/smilelineallineatori-xmwrtf/databases/(default)/documents/orders/".$object_unique_id;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
                                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
                                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                                    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json),
                                    'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PATCH'),
                                CURLOPT_URL             => $url . '?key='.$firestore_key,
                                CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'cURL',
                                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $json
                               )
                );

$response = curl_exec( $curl ); 
curl_close( $curl );    
//Show result
echo $response . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase POST using curl via terminal timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077629/firebase-post-using-curl-via-terminal-timeout)

Comment: I want the upload to take place automatically from my web server where the json file is present, to the firebase database